# Bundle product to look as Single product

Tags: magento2, bundle

We were looking for a solution for ages and we are really desperate now.

We want to sell few products as a one. For example, we are selling the camera at a fixed price and we want to add for free the SD Card, Tripod and batteries. All these additional items are single products and need to be included on the packing slips and invoices with SKUs for inventory and warranty purposes.

We have tried BUNDLE product but there is no option to remove completely customization options from the product page and it is impossible to add this product to the cart from products list page directly by clicking on ADD TO CART button.

The perfect solution for us would be to have the option to list and configure like a bundle product but to look and behave from the frontend exactly as a SIMPLE product but when added to the cart will add few instead of just one product same time.

We also selling those kits on eBay and Amazon (as a simple product) and we need M2E PRO to be able to create orders in the same way (all products listed separately)

Will appreciate any suggestions on how we can achieve this or at least something similar. Are there any extensions or modules can do this? We are also interested in a paid solutions.

How are others selling items with free add-ons?

Thank you

Comment: There is probably no option to completely remove the customization options from the GUI - But that's certainly possible with a Custom Theme/module to modify the Template.

Comment: Thank you @MackieeE, but do you know anything about any extension/module or theme that can remove it? Been looking almost everywhere already.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for a similar solution. Did you ever find one? I did find a third party extension that appears to do what you are looking for. I have not tried it as it does not seem to work with our needs of configurable selections, but for adding various simple products into a cleaner bundle page that looks closer to a simple product, this appears it should work: https://www.aheadworks.com/blog/magento-2-simple-bundle-product/

Comment: Unfortunately, I was forced to get own custom module created for both Magento 1 and Magento 2. However, it appears to be a fairly easy task. An observer that checks products attributes with a list of SKUs and if any than adding those items to the quote just before an order is created.